# Error: I can't jump from a position in the preview to the same position in the tex file

Tags: texworks, live-preview

While using TeXworks installed by MiKTeX, I am trying to jump from a position in the PDF to the position in the tex file, and it isn't working today. The error message is

> Cannot read file "C:/folderpath...":
>
> Access is denied.

Where "C:/folderpath..." is the folder that contains the TeX file. I've tried restarting my computer, putting the settings back to default, deleting the log and aux files, and there is no open PDF in another PDF viewer. Do you know how I might be able to solve this problem?

Comment: Had the same problem on Win 10; it was caused by Cyrillic characters in the file path since the system language is English. Try removing all special characters from the file path and see if the problem continue.

Comment: Try also:
(1) deleting all auxiliary files, in particular the .synctex.gz file
(2) running TeXWorks as administrator.

Comment: Update: I uninstalled and re-installed MiKTeX, and the jumping only started working again when I re-installed packages.